# Nested route is not working as expected - React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My code is

```
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact render={() => <Redirect to='/route' />} />
          <Route path='/route/' exact render={() => <Component />} />
          <Route path='/route/subroute/:id+' exact render={() => <Component1/>} />
          <Route path='/route/subroute/subsubroute1/:id+' exact render={() => <Component2 />} />
          <Route path='/route/subroute/subsubroute2/:id+' exact render={() => <Component3 />} />
          <Route path='/route/:subroute+' exact render={() => <Component4 />} />
          <Route render={() => <Redirect to='/notfound' />} />
        </Switch>
```

Now when I am hitting `history.push(/route/subroute/id)` it is working

But when I try to open `history.push(/route/subroute/subroute1/id)` it is not opening page for me. I tried to go through the documents but all things seem to be in place. What am i missing.

Comment: Move this route below then try
 <Route path='/route/subroute/:id+' exact render={() => <Component1/>} />

Answer (score 0):

`+` operator at `/route/subroute/:id+` makes you match `/route/subroute/subsubroute1/123` for `Component1` route, with a param `subsubroute1/123`.

remove the `+` and it should work as expected.

alternatively, if you really need to use `+`, you can move down `Component1`, and `Component2` will be matched properly since `react-router-dom` matches the first route that matches the given path:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/' exact render={() => <Redirect to='/route' />} />
  <Route path='/route/' exact render={() => <Component />} />
  <Route path='/route/subroute/subsubroute1/:id+' exact render={() => <Component2 />} />
  <Route path='/route/subroute/subsubroute2/:id+' exact render={() => <Component3 />} />
  <Route path='/route/subroute/:id+' exact render={() => <Component1/>} />
  <Route path='/route/:subroute+' exact render={() => <Component4 />} />
  <Route render={() => <Redirect to='/notfound' />} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: But I need + in each because it's a slug so it can be anything!

Comment: `/route/subroute/:id` matches `/route/subroute/my_product_slug`, with `my_product_slug` as param. not entirely sure the issue about removing it, is about some special chars?

Comment: @Niki if you really need it you can move it down Component1 route